# Add class to the last four "a" elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<a id="aitems" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="<?= $block->getItemUrl($item)?>"><?=$item['name']?>
```

I have this "a" tag that is rendering 5 elements that are menu options. But I need that 4 of those 5 elements to open a new url on a different tab that's why I've added the target class.
But of course if I do this way then the first "a" element will open on a new tab too and I dont want that.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
 function addClass(){
        const list = document.querySelector('#aitems');

        // list[0].removeClass("target");
        list[0].addClass("test1");
        list.firstElementChild.classList.add("test");
    }
    addClass();
```

I'm just trying or to remove the class target from the first element or add the class target to the other 4 elements.
It's always giving me errors that can't read classList or addClass.
I've already tried with getElementById or byClassName

I'm doing this on a .phtml file.

Comment: JavaScript cannot see your PHP code, what's the generated HTML? In any case, your template has a static `id` attribute. You cannot have duplicate IDs just like you can't have different cars with the same registration plate.

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually solved the problem ill leave it here if someone needs it

```html
<a class="model-a" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="<?= $block->getItemUrl($item)?>"><?=$item['name']?>
</a>
```

```js
function addClass() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.model-a');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[0].classList.add('newclass');
    divs[0].removeAttribute('target');
  }
}
addClass();
```

The `classList.add` is not necessary but I will leave it.